# How do I automatically svn merge when automated tests pass?

Tags: svn, testing, build, merge

After each commit into 'trunk', we automatically run a bunch of tests against trunk. When those tests pass, I'd like an automated merge into a branch called 'tests-passed'. When the tests fail, no merge should happen, but once the problem is fixed on 'trunk' at the next or a later commit, all the changes should be merged.

The point is to have a branch that has the same content as trunk, but that is just a tad more sane than 'trunk' because at least the automated tests have passed.

I have a script that tries to do that manually but it's a hack using custom properties that doesn't always work correctly -- as I just found out. How do I best make Subversion do this?

Comment: How do you plan to handle merge conflicts?

Comment: I don't think there should be any merge conflicts: 'tests-passed' always has the same content as 'trunk', except when HEAD on 'trunk' does not pass the tests, in which case it has the same content as 'trunk' the last time the tests did pass.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run these commands at the root of a working copy of tests-passed whenever you have determined that a new trunk revision `<somerev>` has passed the tests:

```
svn update
svn merge http://example.com/svn/myproject/trunk -r 0:<somerev>
svn commit -m "merged trunk revisions up to <somerev> into tests-passed"
```

Whenever you use the merge command, SVN will record the merges in the `svn:mergeinfo` property. So the above command should automatically determine which revisions in the range `0:<somerev>` are eligible for merging, excluding any merges that have already been done.

Like you said in a comment, conflicts are not expected. But sometimes I've seen unexpected conflicts occur anyway when merging a range of SVN revisions containing renames. To get rid of these conflicts, you can use the `--accept theirs-full` option with the merge command to always accept the trunk state.

Comment: Ah, the "automatically determine which revisions ... are eligible" is cool, I didn't know that. I thought I had to somehow parse this out myself, which sounded ugly.

How do you suggest that I find <somerev>? I tried 'svnversion trunk', or does it need to be +1?

Comment: @Johannes: it does not need to be +1. For example, if the latest successfull build is for revision 100, you can merge `-r 0:100`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Continuous Integration Tool for that. One pretty popular: Hudson

http://hudson-ci.org/

You can script that kind of behaviour there.

Comment: Again, my question is about the svn part of it, not the scheduling or scripting part. Unless Hudson has some svn magic that I don't know about? (Our setup here does use Hudson to run the builds and the tests in response to checkins on 'trunk')

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine using the test suite to do it.

In my experience I would run an ANT script to test my code, and have a final conditional to execute the branch if the tests were successful.

Comment: We do indeed run the tests with ant, and we have a final condition just as you say. The question is: how do I make svn do the right merge based on that condition?

Comment: Do you guys follow the Name_spacing with every new code. (code_ versioning) might help in this situation.

Comment: I would need to look into ANT scripts a little further but a work around might be to set up an ant script to branch your code regularly, say every 2, 5, or 30 minutes, only if it passes all your test.  The draw back being that instead of immediate integration it would be 2, 5, or 30 minute integration.  Maybe reevaluate your requirements and develop an alternative solution?

Comment: I don't want to create a new branch at every commit on 'trunk'. That is very disruptive to those developers who work off 'tests-passed'. Instead I want to have one branch into which merges occur, but only when the tests pass.